# How do I pass a Ajax Json Response to a php script?

Tags: php, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an *Ajax* `xmlHttpRequest` which gets some data from one server. I need to format this response in a desired format string and publish it on another server.

I am using a *php* script to publish this new string. Here, how do I pass my response from *Ajax* script to my *php* script?

Comment: The data comes in with JavaScript, you could rebuild the JSON to a String in JS. To send it to a PHP Script I would use an API call. This is a very broad question though, you might want to be a lot more specific about what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You pass an "ajax json response" to php script just like you do any other ajax calls. Just find your favourite way for serializing/deserializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Within your script, do

```
  var url = //This is the location of your php script
  var data = "Just a string"

  $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "POST",
     dataType: "JSON",
     data:{
          data
       },
     success:function(response){
           console.log(response + " from server")
     },
     error:function(error){
            console.log("error, something happened"  , error )
      }
  })
```

In you PHP script

```
 <?php 

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['data']) ):

           $string = $_POST['data'];

          echo json_encode( "I'm returning to Javascript " . $string  )


    enif;
```

Comment: I am using xmlHttpRequest() to get the data from the first server. I am doinh something like this -

Comment: ar xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
 {  
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
  {
   var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
   //console.log(response);
   response.result.forEach(function(item)
   {
    if(item.variable === "payload")
    {
     console.log('id is: ', item.id);
     console.log('Time is: ', item.time);
     newString = item.id+item.time;
     console.log('New string is: ', newString );
    }
   });
 }
 } 
 //xmlHttp.open("GET", "myURL", true); // true for asynchronous 
 xmlHttp.send(null);

Comment: Sorry I posted it by mistake